# Getting the realm file of the MongoDB realm database (Android React Native)

Tags: android, react-native, realm

I am using MongoDB Realm database (@realm/react": "^0.4.1" , "realm": "11.0.0") in a React Native Expo Development client on a real Android device and VSCode on Windows 10.

Please note that my database is not empty and is working fine.

In order to use Realm Studio [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/studio/), I am looking for the realm file, but I can't find it.

"realm.path" and "Realm.defaultPath" calls both give:

> Realm file is located at: /data/data/com.myappname/files/default.realm

But on my Android device " /Android/data/com.myappname/files/" folder is emply
and I have no "/data/data..." folder apparently. Same thing on my PC.

PS: Please note that this question is not a duplicate for this configuration. I checked already.

Answer (score 1):

To access the realm file located at `/data/data/com.myappname/files/default.realm`, you need to use adb since it's in the internal storage:

1. Connect your Android device to your PC, enable USB debugging in Developer options.
2. Open a terminal/command prompt, and run adb devices to confirm the connection.
3. Use `adb pull /data/data/com.myappname/files/default.realm /path/to/save` to copy the file to your PC.
4. Open the copied file with Realm Studio to inspect its content.

You'll need adb (Android Debug Bridge) from the Android SDK Platform Tools if you haven't installed it yet.

Remember, each time you make changes to the database on the device, you'll need to repeat these steps to get the updated realm file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried but I have a "adb: error: failed to stat remote object '/data/data/com.podcastcutter1/files/default.realm': Permission denied". I opened the terminal as Admin.    I did "adb pull /data/data/com.podcastcutter1/files/default.realm D:\Temp"

Comment: I aslo tried:   adb root =>
"adbd cannot run as root in production builds"